# Empty photo album using ALAssetsLibrary causes UIButton to be hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, alassetslibrary

I'm using a bit of code to simply be able to set a thumbnail `UIButton` to be hidden or not, and if it's not hidden, grab the last thumbnail from the `ALAssetsGroup` and set the `UIButton`'s image to that thumbnail. However this code fails if you create a new photo album in the Photos App, and leave it empty without any photos; it fails because the photo choose `UIButton` should not be hidden as there is indeed other valid photos in the Photos app to pick from: Here's a screenshot of what I'm describing:

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to solve this? Thanks

[image]

Here is the code I'm using from two methods:

```
- (void)getThumbnailForPhotoLibraryButton
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    if ([ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        [assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
         {
             if (group)
             {
                *stop = YES;

                 NSArray *photoArray = [self getContentFrom:group withAssetFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

                 if (photoArray.count > 0)
                 {
                     UIImage *thumbnail = [photoArray objectAtIndex:0];

                     [self.photoLibraryButton setImage:thumbnail forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                     self.photoLibraryButton.hidden = NO;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     self.photoLibraryButton.hidden = YES;
                 }
             }
         }
         failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
         {}];
    }
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getContentFrom:(ALAssetsGroup *)group withAssetFilter:(ALAssetsFilter *)filter
{
    NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [group setAssetsFilter:filter];

    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if (result)
        {
             *stop = YES;

            [contentArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]]];
        }
    }];

    return contentArray;
}
```

Comment: FYI - `[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]` does not return a `BOOL`. It returns an enum. You need to check against a specific value for the code to work properly.

Comment: How does your code fail? Please explain better. What about your code doesn't work as you expected?

Comment: Response to 2nd comment: I described the issue: the photo button is hidden when it shouldn't be, because there is indeed other images in the photos app. I fixed the return type in revised question now

Comment: A user can have hundreds of photo albums. Most with photos, some with none. Your logic needs to handle this.

Comment: That's what question is for. Elaborate

Comment: Actually, you need to elaborate. It's your logic. How do you wish to determine when the button is hidden or not? Which album's thumbnail do you want? You could choose to iterate just the camera roll (`ALAssetsGroupLibrary`) if that's what you want.

Comment: Nope, I'm enumerating every photo in the Photos app and simply grabbing the most recent one.

Comment: No, you only iterate a single group because you do `*stop = YES`. This mean only one group will be processed.

Comment: if (group && group.numberOfAssets >= 1) Yep that solved it! dumb dumb dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rmaddy pointed out, I was stopping the block too early with a wrong kind of conditional check:

This solved it:

```
if ([ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{
    [assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if (group && group.numberOfAssets >= 1)
         {
            *stop = YES;

             NSArray *photoArray = [self getContentFrom:group withAssetFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

             if (photoArray.count >= 1)
             {
                 UIImage *thumbnail = [photoArray objectAtIndex:0];

                 [self.photoLibraryButton setImage:thumbnail forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 self.photoLibraryButton.hidden = NO;
             }
             else
             {
                 self.photoLibraryButton.hidden = YES;
             }
         }
     }
     failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {}];
}
```